# pyaudio installtion error in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-prompt

I am using python 2.7 in my windows 10 system. When i try to install pyaudio from command prompt using the command

```
easy_install pyaudio
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ankit>easy_install pyaudio
Searching for pyaudio

Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyaudio/
Best match: pyaudio 0.2.8

Downloading http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/packages/pyaudio-0.2.8.tar.gz#md5=

Processing pyaudio-0.2.8.tar.gz
Running PyAudio-0.2.8\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir

 c:\users\ankit\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-ejvxxc\PyAudio-0.2.8\egg-dist-tmp-42gjeh

warning: no files found matching '*.c' under directory 'test'

_portaudiomodule.c
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:

 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory

 error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

I also tried

```
pip install pyaudio
```

And this time getting this error message:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ankit>pip install pyaudio

You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Collecting pyaudio

Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyaudio
Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable

 (use --allow-external pyaudio to allow).

No distributions at all found for pyaudio
```

Please help me out.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: First run your IDE or CMD as Administrator and run the following: pip install pipwin  /  pipwin install pyaudio

Answer (score 2):

Look at the output:

```
Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable    
(use --allow-external pyaudio to allow).
```

You can install it adding extra arguments to pip:

```
pip install pyaudio --allow-external pyaudio --allow-unverified pyaudio
```

Also, do you have [PortAudio installed](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html)?

Comment: It seems the OP has little to no experience building a C library from source. In this case it will be simpler for the OP to install a pre-built package such as http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/packages/pyaudio-0.2.8.py27.exe.

Comment: I am having a similar issue as OP. I tried the solution from user2386841 but it tells me `no such option --allow-external` perhaps pip has been updated since and I must try something different.

Comment: Now there're several package-management tool on windows. Both "Vcpkg" and "winget" have Portaudo included.  https://winget.run/pkg/intxcc/pyaudio  https://vcpkg.info/port/portaudio