# Error "Could not find PyAudio; check installation" on Windows

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have simple code in python to recognise my voice and convert it in text. I am using speech recognition.

But I am getting error "Could not find PyAudio; check installation". How to fix?

Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Speak anything')
    audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        global command
        command = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said : {}'.format(text))
    except:
        print('Sorry,coud not recognize')
```

Comment: You have to install it separately [Pyaudio](https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio/releases)

Comment: I install it and that doesnt fix anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyaudio installtion error in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160102/pyaudio-installtion-error-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Install pyaudio.

if you are using jupyter notebook on anaconda prompt then

```
conda install pyaudio
```

if you are using jupyter notebook using cmd then on jupyter cell,

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pyaudio
```

if you are running python file on cmd then,

```
pip3 install pyaudio #for python3
```

Answer (score -1):

even i faced py-audio error so you can install py-audio with the help of unofficial libraries  install it with the help of powershell in windows
[python unoffical libraries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31059009)