# PyAudio error Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Tags: python

I'm working on a voice recognition project using the Google Speech Recognition API and every time I try to run the program, it gives me the same error each time:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pook.py", line 4, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "Random File name", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "Random File name", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I've tried to see every post with this same exact error, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Does `import pyaudio` succeed?  If not, there's your problem.  Install the pyaudio package, if you can.

Comment: I've already tried using pip to install PyAudio, but the error said that it couldn't build a wheel. After that, I decided to look online for the PyAudio wheel and I still couldn't manage to get any of them to run

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55984350/3019689

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55984129/  but I cannot close this question as a duplicate because the earlier question's answers have not been accepted or upvoted.  However, I have just posted a new answer there that might help you.

Comment: Consider this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60898914/8227403 Hope this will help.